# Small Clearance Square Bit

Tags: repair, tools, furniture

I'm trying to take apart an old bed frame. The fasteners are square head bolts, but they're tucked away with only 1/2" of clearance to access them.

I can't find square head bits shorter than an inch, so I've got no idea how it was put together in the first place.

Is there such a tool out there?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can barely make it out, but it looks like a pin-and-slot arrangement. Bump the rail with your palm away from the camera. The bracket that's retained by the screw should slide off the pin we see deeper in. If it doesn't budge, use a mallet or a hammer and block of wood.

Comment: Agreed, no one is expected to turn that screw to disassemble it.  Even with an array of ideal, custom tools, you could only back it out about 10mm before *no* tool would fit!  And the screw will be longer than that.

Comment: If by some means that square-drive fastener has been loosened a little already, it may be necessary to re-tighten it before the pin will be able to slide past.

Comment: Good eye, I was trying to figure out just what I was looking at. I knew unscrewing it wasn't the answer.